# OpenSSL ECDSA sign and verify file

Tags: openssl, cryptography

I would like to sign and verify a pdf with elliptic curve. I got some code but it dosen't work.

Create private key:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -noout -out private.pem
```

Create public key:

```
openssl ec -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

Sign file:

```
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 test.pdf > hash openssl dgst
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -inkey private.pem -keyform PEM -in hash > signature
```

Verify file:

```
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -verify public.pem -signature signature.bin data
```

The part to sign and verify dosen't work.

Comment: Just a caution for incoming readers: **native PDF signatures according to ISO 32000 do not simply calculate the hash over the entire raw file**. So in the current question, the file `test.pdf` could be interpreted as if it had any other extension, e.g. `.txt`. This means that the signature will be calculated over the entire raw file and it won't produce a native PDF signature, i.e. the type of signature that can be interpreted by Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are not actually signing the file, but signing the hash.

I tried the following and it gave me the desired output:

```
Create signature:
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -sign private.pem test.pdf > signature.bin

Verify signature:
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -verify public.pem -signature signature.bin test.pdf
```

Comment: How do you do it in an OpenSSL session, for the case you use an engine?

Answer (score 8):

Since -ecda-with-SHA1 is not in the man for dgst and there is no -ecda-with-SHA256 I would recommend :

Sign :

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private.pem test.pdf > signature.bin
```

Verify :

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify public.pem -signature signature.bin test.pdf
```

Comment: source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856059/openssl-ecdsa-sign-and-verify-file

Comment: Wouldn't work. ```$ openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private.pem test.pdf > signature.bin 
Error Signing Data
8123:error:0606B06E:digital envelope routines:EVP_SignFinal:wrong public key type:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.6/src/crypto/evp/p_sign.c:99:```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you need an engine, you can also do it in an OpenSSL session:

```
openssl
OpenSSL> engine -vvvv -t dynamic -pre SO_PATH:someengine.so -pre ID:someengine -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD
OpenSSL> dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -out signature.bin -sign private.pem test.pdf
OpenSSL> dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -verify public.pem -signature signature.bin test.pdf
```

*dgst* offers also the `-engine` option, but here it takes the engine loaded earlier. If required, simply add `-engine someengine`.